# jenkins common build number

Tags: git, jenkins

Is it possible to share BUILD_NUMBER between 2 jobs?
For example, a job B should use the next BUILD_NUMBER from the project A.

When I said 'share' this mean that both jobs should use the same counter automatically.

For example:

I have two different branches: stable and testing.
Once per 3 hour jenkins is checking for new commits and build new package in case some changes were merged into the branch.

I need that jenkins automatically can make builds like

```
testing01
testing02
testing03
stable04
testing05
stable06
testing07
..
```

Comment: in your example, do you have a different job for each of the two different branches? so like we could call the testing branch "job A" and the stable branch "job B"? is it just the "stable" branch that polls every three hours? the other branch builds more frequently?

Comment: > in your example, do you have a different job for each of the two different branches?     

yes, I have. If it is possible to build stable and testing packages from the stable and testing branches respectively in terms of one job then please describe how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

- making job A leave its build number in a file,
- making job B set its build number from that file (using the [JENKINS
  Next Build Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin))

That would be possible if job B is a job DSL script

```
job('B') {
  properties {
    nextBuildNumber(47)
  }
}
```

Or you could [use the CLI for job A to set job B](https://github.com/jenkinsci/next-build-number-plugin/commit/cd593d7c7a130f24914a68b6b4502fc4d0ab8738)

The problem with both of those approaches is that setting the build number will fail if job B own internal build number was already *greater* than the one job A want to set for job B.
So you need to make sure job B only builds when job A wants.